# How can I save billing information and credit card information in a safe way?

Tags: node.js, express, security, stripe-payments

I want to save credit card information and billing information (Just like Amazon) for each user just they don't have to type it each time they want to pay. I already have the implementation of stripe tokens, It is working and all, this feature is just for having a better User Experience. However, I don't know how can I do this in a safe way, like encrypting all the information.
What is the best way to store this kind of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re going to store credit card information, you need to implement all of the [PCI DSS standard](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/document_library). It’s not optional, your merchant agreement will require that you do so. What that actually involves is far beyond the scope of an answer here — it’s a 139-page document, and it’s quite terse. The brief summary would be: don’t touch this with a barge pole unless you have extensive IT security experience and know what you’re doing.

Comment: Pff i knew this was way harder than it sounds, thanks for the answer I will tell my superior haha :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Stripe you don't have to encrypt any payment information, that's all handled by Stripe if you're using their newer integrations.

- The user enters their details on a form, that is hosted by Stripe(e.g. Elements/Checkout) [0]
- The raw credit card details never touch your system, only Stripe's.
- You receive back a non-sensitive payment **token** from Stripe's API that represents the details entered, but isn't sensitive itself.
- You can use Stripe's API to charge that token or save it for later re-use. [1] There is no PCI burden in doing this, as you're never storing any sensitive payment information, just IDs from the API. [2]

The only thing you need to worry about is keeping your Stripe secret key, well, [secret and secure](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#keeping-your-keys-safe), with standard practises for managing API keys.

[0] - https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart

[1] - https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards

[2] - https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance

Comment: I am already doing this, I just want this "feature" so our clients don't have to type it everytime they want to pay. Still thanks for the answer!!! :)

Comment: `don't have to type it everytime they want to pay` Yep, that's what https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards allows you to do, you save the details to a customer object, save the customer ID in your user's table in your database(for example), and when the user logs in you can use the saved details on the customer object to create charges.